# How to count matching Sell-Orders for all Buy-Orders with dynamic attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I want to retrieve all buy orders with a count of matching buy orders in a single query.
A match would be a sell order that satisfies all attributes (greater or equal) and is cheaper than the buy order. Is that even possible?

This is my table structure:

#### Attributes

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Area (m2) |
| 2 | Rooms |
| ... | ... |

#### Sell Orders

| id | title | price | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flat #1 | 500.000,00€ | ... |
| 2 | House #1 | 1.000.000,00€ | ... |
| ... | .... | .... | ... |

#### Sell Order Attributes

| sell_order_id | attribute_id | value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 90 | ... |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 239 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

#### Buy Orders

| id | offer | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 600.000,00€ | ... |
| 2 | 150.000,00€ | ... |

#### Buy Order Attributes

| buy_order_id | attribute_id | value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 80 | ... |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 200 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried solving it in MySQL Workbench but I could not figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the sell order id and buy order id is related. If not, then there is no relations in your data between sell and buy tables. You can try something like below to get the raw answer. First cte creates marker for all attributes. Second CTE gets all sales ids that fulfil all the attribute needs. Then final select gets the cases where buy orders are in line with sales attribute needs and price less than the buy order.

```
   with cte as ( 
select s.*
case
        when a.[attribute_id] = 'whatever attribute you choose' and a.value >= 'whatever the benchmark is' then 1
        when a.[attribute_id] = 'whatever 2nd attribute you choose' and a.value >= 'whatever the benchmark is' then 1
            else 0
            end as marker
    from [Sell Orders]  s
        inner join [Sell Order Attributes] a on s.id = a.sell_order_id
),

cte2 as (
select id , sum(marker)
from cte
group by id
having sum(marker) = 2 --however many attributes you are testing
)

select *
    from [Buy Orders] b on b.id = s.id
        inner join [Buy Order Attributes] c on b.id = c.buy_order_id
        inner join  cte2 t on t.id = b.id


        Where  t.price < b.price
```

Answer (score -1):

As you don't store price and offer as decimal or other numeric types you need always to cast it, which will take some time, besides monetary datatypes arent't supported, so you should redesign your tables.

the rest is a lot of joins with the correct ON clause.

It will compare the price against the offer and all attributes that match

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*,b.*
FROM Sell_Orders s JOIN Sell_Order_Attributes sa ON sa.`sell_order_id` = s.`id`
JOIN Buy_Orders b ON CAST( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.`offer`,'€',''),'.',''),',','.') AS DECIMAL(20,2))  >= CAST( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(s.price,'€',''),'.',''),',','.') AS DECIMAL(20,2))  JOIN Buy_Order_Attributes ba ON ba.`buy_order_id` = b.`id` 
  and ba.`attribute_id` = sa.`attribute_id`and sa.`value` >= ba.`value`
```

| id | title | price | id | offer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flat #1 | 500.000,00€ | 1 | 600.000,00€ |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BFM-JQC2)